# parametric modeling with array and curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can the construction of parametric partition element be made so that the "twist" (encircled) be placed along the curve through non destructive means?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the untwisted section retain a constant diameter?

Comment: The length of the twist needs to be the same (not stretched due to any kind of deformation). Untwisted (also the twisted) part is of rectangular profile. i think we need to asisgn vertex to twisted portion...But how to achieve it?